# Get start of line without taking soft line breaks into account

Tags: winapi, vb6

In a RichTextBox, when sending EM_LINEINDEX to get the index of the first character of a line, the index will be affected by soft line breaks. Consider the following text box:

[image: example of richtextbox with soft line break]

Calling `SendMessage hWnd, EM_LINEINDEX, 1, 0` will result in 25, while I would expect it to return 45 (line 1 should be "this is another line" not "and continues here").

Is there a way to get the *real* first char index of the second line using WinAPI calls?

Comment: EM_LINEINDEX does not differentiate between soft breaks and hard breaks when word wrapping is involved.

Comment: `EM_LINECOUNT` isn't going to work for you, either. It, too, counts lines caused by soft breaks.

Comment: You could turn off wordwrap, calculate the index and then turn it back on again. If you use WM_SETREDRAW it might not even be visible.

Comment: If there really is no other way, I suppose I will have to resort to what you say, or some other similar method, but even if I wanted to, RichTextBoxes don't have a WordWrap property that I can set (that I know of)... it just does the wrapping. The only way I've found to simulate it is to set its `RightMargin` property to a very large value, but that feels even dirtier... I was thinking there might be a way because in .NET WinForms you have the `Lines` property, and I thought WinForms was heavily based on the native windows controls...

Comment: Windows Forms' `RichTextBox` (derived from `TextBoxBase`) simply parses the control contents, to produce the array of lines (see [TextBoxBase.Lines](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,37cabfde1449b18f)).

Answer (score 0):

This is from a working program. I play with right margin.

```
Sub mnuWordWrap_Click()
'On Error Resume Next
If txtNote.RightMargin = 0 Then
    txtNote.RightMargin = &HFFFE&
    mnuWordWrap.Checked = False
Else
    txtNote.RightMargin = 0
    mnuWordWrap.Checked = True
End If
txtNote.SetFocus
txtNote_SelChange
End Sub
```

In another program I do this, though this is Vista's RTF window (not a control so not the old ANSI version of RTF as in VB6)

```
If mnuViewWordWrap.Checked = True Then
                Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETTARGETDEVICE, GetDC(gRtfHwnd), -1800)
            If Ret = 0 Then ReportError "Form Resize", "Set Target Device"
        Else
            Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETTARGETDEVICE, GetDC(gRtfHwnd), 4000000)
            If Ret = 0 Then ReportError "Form Resize", "Set Target Device"
        End If
```